# Sort date by day before and by night after in one query

Tags: mysql, sorting

(first : I'm french and I'm sorry if I make some grammaticals faults...)

I have a table with TV programs. I want, in one query, to search the programs in this table and to sort the results with all the programs of the day before the programs of the night.

I have an input name fullDateStart with the date in DATETIME format for extract HOUR().

I use a LEFT JOIN in my research. Here my actual request :

```
SELECT programId, programTitle, COUNT(*) AS score,
ROUND(startDate / 1000) AS start, ROUND(endDate / 1000) AS end
FROM people_appearances AS a
LEFT JOIN programsTable AS b ON a.programId = b.program_id
WHERE peopleId = :id AND timestamp > :twoWeeksAgo AND programId != 0
AND redif = 0 AND channel_id IN(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)
GROUP BY programId
ORDER BY score DESC, start DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Here my try with UNION :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT fullDateStart, programId, programTitle, COUNT(*) AS score1,
    ROUND(startDate / 1000) AS start, ROUND(endDate / 1000) AS end
    FROM people_appearances AS a
    LEFT JOIN db.epg_programs AS b ON a.programId = b.program_id
    WHERE HOUR(fullDateStart) > 6 AND HOUR(fullDateStart) <= 23
    AND peopleId = 826 AND timestamp > 1353420511000 AND programId != 0
    AND redif = 0 AND channel_id IN(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)
    GROUP BY programId

    UNION
    SELECT fullDateStart, programId, programTitle, COUNT(*) AS score2,
    ROUND(startDate / 1000) AS start, ROUND(endDate / 1000) AS end
    FROM people_appearances AS c
    LEFT JOIN db.epg_programs AS d ON c.programId =d.program_id
    WHERE HOUR(fullDateStart) >= 0 AND HOUR(fullDateStart) <= 6
    AND peopleId = 826 AND timestamp > 1353420511000 AND programId != 0
    AND redif = 0 AND channel_id IN(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9)
    GROUP BY programId
    ) AS s3
ORDER BY score1 DESC,start DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is somebody can help me please ? (I try with a Union with two request [one for the day, one for the night] but I don't succeed to sort the results, even if they was in two requests...)

Comment: `order by score, start, hour(fullDateStart)`? or do you "9am" to come before "3am", since that's day v.s. night?

Comment: No it's not that simple, I have to sort with these arguments :
First : 7h -> 23h
Second : 0h -> 6h

Comment: `order by scor, start, if (hour(fulldatestart) >= 7, 1, 0), hour(fulldatestart)` then. set a priority based on the hour, then within that priority, sort by the actual hour.

Comment: I tried your code but nothing change... (i don't understand the condition, is this return 1 or 0 ? if yes what is the sort condition ?)

Comment: order/where can use arbitrary values. [if()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is a normal mysql function. and I just realized I have the logic backwards. it should be `if(..., 0, 1)` or at least `if(...,1,0) DESC`.

Comment: Yes i get it. I succed to have the day before the night by put the condition at first of the sort arguments. Now the problem is : I have my results sort by hour and not sort by score... Isn't it possble to cut the results in two part (day before night) and inside of this two part to sort them by score ?

Comment: sure, just change the position of the various `order by` arguments. the more "left" an argument is (closer to the `order by`), the higher its sort priority is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your query is the `order by`.  You are ordering everything first by the score, then by the start date.

If the goal is to keep everything in one day, then do something like:

```
order by score desc, date(fulldatestart),
         (case when hour(fulldatestart) between 7 and 23 then 1
               else 2
          end),
         hour(fulldatestart)
```

I added a third clause for the `order by`, so programs with the same score are ordered by hour.

If you want the early morning hours associated with the *previous* day, then you need to do something like:

```
order by score desc, date(fulldatestart - interval 7 hour),
         hour(fulldatestart - interval 7 hour)
```

(once you subtract 7 hours, you can keep things in the order by hour.)

Comment: technically, you don't need the between clause. just `hour() >= 7`. mysql should never return hour 24+, since that'd be hour 0+ of the next day.

Comment: No, it's not extactly what I want but it's near. I want all programs wich hours are include in 7h -> 23h (whatever the day) and after the last on, I want the programs of the night (hour include in 0h -> 6h). In those 2 parts i want the results are sort by score then by date (desc). So if i have 10 results (5 of the day, 5 of the night), the 5 of the day have to be first and sort by score and date. After the 5th day result the first of the night result can appear.

Comment: If you want a example, in this link : [link](http://tvsearch.leankr.com/search/search.php?q=Vanessa%20Paradis&type=People&id=826&page=1) "the result 50mn Inside" should not be in first page, watever it's score, because there is more results between 7h and 23h before.

Comment: Ok I succeed thank's to you Marc B. The answer was :

ORDER BY if (HOUR(fullDateStart) >= 7, 0, 1) ASC, score DESC, date DESC

Thank you verry myuch you too ! (Marc B. you rock !)